# Typescript Global Variable across Files

Tags: javascript, scope, typescript

I created a variable in a .ts file that has no module or class. It mostly looks just like a plain JavaScript file. I want this variable to accessible in another .ts file inside of a class that is inside of a variable.

So for example I have:

**foo.ts**

```
var foo = "some stuff";
```

**bar.ts**

```
module Bar {
    export class BarClass {
        function getFoo() {
             return foo;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this is the best way to do it. I've tried using the window.bar global but that doesn't seem to work. I'm new to TypeScript jumping into a larger codebase so please let me know if you need any further clarification on anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TypeScript files don't know about anything you've done in other TypeScript files unless they have a reference to them.  So at the top of `bar.ts` you should have a line

```
/// <reference path="foo.ts" />
```

Comment: Would I need to do `declare var foo:any;` too?

Comment: Nope.  Declare is for assuring the compiler that something is going to exist, that it doesn't otherwise know about.  Usually something loaded by a 3rd party library.  The compiler will know about foo because it will have a reference to the file where it's created.

Comment: Awesome. This answer helped clear up a lot of problems for me. Thanks!

Comment: What if the external variable is a simple JavaScript variable?

Comment: @MathiasLykkegaardLorenzen you need to create a declaration file (.d.ts) if it doesnt exist yet (look on https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped)

Answer (score 6):

From your question, not sure if it was a compilation, IDE or runtime issue that you had. Still, thought I'd share that a good way to avoid some of these issues with globals is to create your own "types" file and list it in your `typeRoots` property in your `tsconfig.json`.

For example, something I've done in the past is create a shortcut to console.log that also colours messages with a style I wish. Like so...

```
const pretty = (style: string, ...anything) => {
  anything.forEach(something => 
    console.log(`%c ${something} `, style));
  return moment().format('[Logged @] HH:MM:SS');
}
```

So I don't have to `declare var pretty` in every TS file I use it, I'd create `src/myTypes/globals/index.d.ts`

```
...
declare function pretty(style: string, ...anything);
...
```

And then in my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": ["src/myTypes"]
```

So, in your case, if `foo` was a var that you know would be there in runtime you could simply `declare var foo: string;` in your types file, list it in your typeRoots and use it happily in all your project files without any further config.

Comment: I like this answer. Could you declare const's here as well?